Replacing an xps 13 9360 (2017-ish)
I need to replace that laptop. It was high-end at that time, but it is good enough for me today still. It served me well.
In other words - I don't need to spend for a high-end today.
What is a good replacement today? I'd want 16GB Ram, a decent cpu comparable to that xps, 512Gb SSD, and I don't need the touch screen, that was overkill.
